# react-native open a modal inside a modal

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-sectioned-multi-select](https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select) library. I want to open another modal view after I click the confirm button.

I feel like I did the code correctly but this isn't working. Is it possible to open a new modal inside this library?

```
const items = [
  {
    name: "Fruits",
    id: 0,
    children: [{
        name: "Apple",
        id: 10,
      },{
        name: "Strawberry",
        id: 17,
      },{
        name: "Pineapple",
        id: 13,
      },{
        name: "Banana",
        id: 14,
      },{
        name: "Watermelon",
        id: 15,
      },{
        name: "Kiwi fruit",
        id: 16,
      }]
  }]

export default class TestScreen extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
      modalVisible: false,
    }
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  onSelectedItemsChange = (selectedItems) => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
    console.log(selectedItems)
  }

  openModal = () => {
   return(
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
         <View style={{width:300, height:400, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
           <Modal
             animationType="slide"
             transparent={false}
             visible={this.state.modalVisible}
             onRequestClose={() => {
               Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
             }}>
             <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
               <View>
                 <Text>Hello World!</Text>

                 <TouchableHighlight
                   onPress={() => {
                     this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                   }}>
                   <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
               </View>
             </View>
           </Modal>

           <TouchableHighlight
             onPress={() => {
               this.setModalVisible(true);
             }}>
             <Text>Show Modal</Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
         </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View>
        <SectionedMultiSelect
          items={items}
          uniqueKey='id'
          subKey='children'
          selectText='Choose some things...'
          showDropDowns={true}
          readOnlyHeadings={true}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
//Here I call the openModal function but nothing appears

          onConfirm={()=> {this.openModal}}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Any comments or advise would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

**Edited**

If I can't open two modals at a time, I want my new modal to open after I close my first modal.

Comment: You have called `openModal()` but inside that there is a condition for modal i.e. `visible={this.state.modalVisible}` where modalVisible is always false, so it will not show any modal.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya thanks for the comments but that doesn't seem to be the problem its still the same.

Comment: any luck @kirimi finding your answer ?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple simultaneously open modals do not work in React Native. You could:

- close the first modal before opening the second one, then reopening the first one when you're done with the second
- roll your own modal using 'position: absolute' styling

Comment: this is true, another solution instead of specifically closing/reopening the parent modal when the child modal needs to be shown is to conditionally render one modal or the other: `return showChildModal ? <ChildModal /> : <ParentModal />`

(also, `position: absolute` has a downside worth noting, unlike in CSS on the web it will always live within the bounding box of its parent element, so won't overlay the whole screen unless the parent is full screen.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure both the `Modal`'s aren't using the same `state values` for the `visible` prop in `Modal`.

You can use `visible` prop as `visible={this.state.modalPage1}`. The state `modalPage1` should be initiated to `bool` value.

So if the scenario is that you are closing the first Modal and opening another one, then

```
this.setState({ 
      modalPage1: false, 
      modalPage2: true
});
```

Hope I could help you. Do comment if any other Doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate multiple modal visibility with [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) using logical operator. 
 Here is the snippet code that might work in your case:

```
{
  this.state.isFirstModalOpen && (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={this.state.isModalOpen}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
        <View>
          <Text>Hello World!</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                isFirstModalOpen: false,
                isSecondModalOpen: true
              });
            }}
          >
            <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}
{
  this.state.isSecondModalOpen && (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={this.state.isSecondModalOpen}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
        <View>
          <Text>Hello World!</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ isSecondModalOpen: false });
            }}
          >
            <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
return (
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
<View>
    <SectionedMultiSelect
      items={items}
      uniqueKey='id'
      subKey='children'
      selectText='Choose some things...'
      showDropDowns={true}
      readOnlyHeadings={true}
      onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
      selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
//Here I call the openModal function but nothing appears
      //onConfirm={()=> {this.openModal}}  <-- change this with
      onConfirm={() => this.setState({modalVisible: true})}
    />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
);
}
```

You dont call directly a modal, you have to toggle the visible state of modal

And then you need to close the modal as well whenever your task is completed, all you need to do is, on click or on Press....

```
    this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
```